# Can SC.get return tracks from two specific users?

Tags: soundcloud

I'd like to specify two user id's in SoundCloud's SC.get('/tracks') function. Is this possible?

something like this:

```
function getTracks() {
    SC.get('/tracks', {
        user_ids: {user_id: 00001, user_id: 000002}
    }, function(tracks) {
        // build a list of tracks from the two soundcloud users
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to filter the /tracks endpoint on user. Sorry!

The closest thing you can do is grab the tracks for each user individually:

```
SC.get('/users/<user_id>/tracks', function(tracks) {
   ...
});
```

So you could do two calls to SC.get() and combine the results.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean you can't filter on user_id at all?

Comment: That's correct. Edited answer with the closest alternative: use two calls to SC.get to get each users tracks individually.

Comment: SC.get('/tracks', { user_id: '462658' }, function (tracks) { ... etc, works for me. Is this correct usage / expected? I'm new to this API.